# How to toggle nested checkboxes (options) on check parent checkbox in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have simple questions list. It has some options and those options has some nested suboptions. 
So need to keep hidden all nested checkboxes until checks parent checkbox.

i tried to do it but could not get it work.

i have tried this so far:

For better understanding please have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2103jxdo/3/)

```
    <div id="app">
  <h2>Questions:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="question in questions">
    <div class="question">{{ question.question }}</div>
    <div class="label__wrap" v-for="option in question.options">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="question.answer" :value="option.option">

          <span>
              {{ option.option }}
          </span>
      </label>

        <div class="sub__label__wrap" v-for="opt in option.subOptions">
              <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" v-model="option.subOptsAnswers" :value=" opt.option">

                  <span>
                      {{ opt.option }}
                  </span>
              </label>
        </div>

    </div>
      <br><br>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: fiddle not updated properly. update options and suboptions data there.

Comment: @dagalti please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rcam67b9/

check the answers array whether the selected answer exist

```
v-if="question.answer.indexOf(option.option) !== -1"
```

Final Code

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Questions:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="question in questions">
    <div class="question">{{ question.question }}</div>
    <div class="label__wrap" v-for="option in question.options">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="question.answer" :value="option.option">

          <span>
              {{ option.option }}
          </span>
      </label>

        <div class="sub__label__wrap" v-for="opt in option.subOptions" v-if="question.answer.indexOf(option.option) !== -1">
              <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" v-model="option.subOptsAnswers" :value=" opt.option">

                  <span>
                      {{ opt.option }}
                  </span>
              </label>
        </div>

    </div>
      <br><br>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```